# Как узнать название используемой темы в терминале на linux?

Tags: linux

1. Как узнать, какую тему я использую через терминал?
2. Как узнать, где находятся все возможные иконки к теме?

Со вторым непонятно. Через <kbd>System → Preferences → Look & Feel → Appearance</kbd> я узнаю что я использую тему BlueMenta. Захожу в папку `usr/share/icons`, а там папки bluementa нет.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотреть тему для Gnome, Unity и Mate через терминал

тема

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme
```

Иконки

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

Иконки хранятся в `$HOME/.icons` (для совместимости), в `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons` и в `/usr/share/pixmaps`. Обход в таком порядке.

`$XDG_DATA_DIRS` это тоже несколько папок
`$HOME/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/` `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/` `/usr/local/share/` `/usr/share/`.

Answer (score 1):

Отображаемое название хранится в `index.theme`, например:

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=Birch
Name[sv]=Björk
```

Папка может называться как-то иначе.

Ещё тема может брать иконки из другой темы, если в ней есть такая директива:

```
[Icon Theme]
Inherits=Adwaita
```

Чтоб собрать все иконки наверное придется пройтись по всем index.theme, во всех папках `$HOME/.icons` (для совместимости), в `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons` и в `/usr/share/pixmaps`, где $XDG_DATA_DIRS это тоже несколько папок (у меня так)

```
$HOME/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/
/usr/local/share/
/usr/share/
```

Обход должен происходить в таком порядке.